# Crypto / Token Auth guidance

Tags: c#, encryption

I've bought some hardware that shares a document on how to authenticate [here](https://www.loxone.com/dede/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/08/0903_Communicating-with-the-Miniserver.pdf):

Crypto is definitely not my thing and I am trying to work out how or even what form of crypto this is to try and find online examples so I can try and communicate using c# and preferable .net core so I can be x-plat.

Now there is code [here](https://github.com/alladdin/node-lox-ws-api/tree/master/lib/Auth) that does just this, except it's in node.js I believe and I dont know the crypto lib

In summary this is what they state in the documentation:

> 2. Acquire the Miniservers public key via “jdev/sys/getPublicKey​” -> {publicKey} a. Store on the client b. Format: X.509 encoded key in
>      ANS.1
> 3. open a WebSocket connection a. use the following path: “ws://{ipOrUrl}:{port}/ws/rfc6455​” b. specify “remotecontrol​” as
>      Sec-WebSocket-Protocol. c. wss:// is not supported by the Miniserver.
> 4. Generate a AES256 key -> {key} (Hex)
> 5. Generate a random AES iv (16 byte) -> {iv} (Hex)
> 6. RSA Encrypt the AES key+iv with the {publicKey}​ -> {session-key} (Base64) a. “{key}:{iv}” is the payload that needs to be encrypted
>      using RSA
> 7. Exchange keys via “jdev/sys/keyexchange/{session-key}​”
> 8. Generate a random salt, hex string (length may vary, e.g. 2 bytes) -> {salt}
> 9. There are two options now: a. If a token exists, then authenticate as described in Authenticating using tokens b. If a token needs to be
>      acquired, proceed as described in Acquiring tokens Config 9.3
>      Communicating with the Miniserver Page 5 of 21
> 10. After either successful token based authentication or acquiring a new token, the socket is authenticated and ready to go.

So I'm pretty sure i'm good with step 2 (Maybe not the format the x.509 encoded key.. I've taken that as strip the padding and just get the base64 values:

```
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http://192.168.0.77");
        using (var request = new LxHttpRequest(builder.Uri))
        {
            CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
            string result = request.GetStringAsync("jdev/sys/getPublicKey", token).Result;
            var res = ResultConverter.Deserialize(result);

            Console.WriteLine(TokenAuth.parsePublicKey(res.Content));
        }
```

Step 3, I have cloned code from [loxnet](https://github.com/serialize/LoxNET) which i think is a good starting point so happy with that..

Step 4/5, is where I'm at:

```
         var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.GenerateIV();
            byte[] iv = aes.IV;
            aes.GenerateKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Key base64: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key));
```

but at about this point my head is pickled and I get annoyed.. I appreciate this feels like an asking for help with homework - but I'm more hoping someone can explain what this is called so I can carry on searching - unless someone can help with examples / snippets, or a suggestion of a nuget package that does the hardwork - I had a look at bouncycastle but that made my eyes want to bleed in trying to understand anything :D :D

Please go easy with the flaming!

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  I understand the scope of the question, but you're up to step 4/5 and... what?  What is the issue here?  Is the code not working or you're unsure what to do now?  Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: I dont know what I need to do next! - I dont understand the steps to know what sort of AES encyption method this so I can find sample code I can adapt!

for example look at the bouncycastle feature list http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Too many different algorithms for me to test each.. surely someone knows what this is?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: @PaulSinnema - not quite -getting closer, but then decided addidng token based auth to one of the existing projects on github might be easier. Happy to take this offline and chat via email as it could get a bit off topic :)

Comment: Ok, you can reach me at paul@sinnema.ch

Answer (score 1):

so I've taken another look at the instructions and just tried to work my way through it.. does this look like i am on the correct track:

```
    private static void CryptoTest()
    {
        byte[] serversPublicKey = GetPublicKey();

        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
        var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: false);

        // Set RSAKeyInfo withthe provided public key. 
        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = serversPublicKey;
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        // Generate New AES key
        var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.GenerateKey();

        byte[] sessionKey;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                // Encrypt the aes key and iv
                writer.Write(aes.Key);
                writer.Write(":");
                writer.Write(aes.IV);
            }

            sessionKey = RSA.Encrypt(stream.ToArray(), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted Session Key (Base64): {Convert.ToBase64String(sessionKey)}");

        // Todo Step 7 send key to server

    }
```